# SBS 2011 keeps adding a static DNS entry for an old IP address

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-sbs-2011

At one point, on our SBS 2011 server, I had 2 IP addresses assigned to the primary NIC. This resulted in Windows adding a static entry for both IPs to the DNS when the DNS server started. This of course caused all manner of confusion, so I eventually removed the secondary IP address. However, every time the DNS server service is restarted, a static entry for the no longer present IP address keeps reappearing. Obviously, there's a reference to this IP somewhere that is causing this, but I have no idea where to look.

Why does Windows keep recreating this DNS entry for an IP that is no longer assigned to the machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel stupid after figuring this one out, but it's obscure enough that it's worth posting the answer in case someone else has the problem.

At some point in the past, while attempting to fix another DNS issue, I had modified the registry key for the DNS service to include a PublishAddresses parameter that included the address in question. Once I modified this value to remove the old ip address, everything worked as expected.

More details on this issue can be found here:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverNIS/thread/3eaf3017-373f-4361-a51f-0a20b2e51067

Quotes from link:

> HKLM\System\ControlSet001\Services\DNS\Parameters\ListenAddress
>   
>  HKLM\System\ControlSet001\Services\DNS\Parameters\PublishAddress
>
> You shouldn't have had to alter the reg to make this work. From the
>   reg entries you showed, it indicated that the DNS service was the
>   culprit registering this data, and not the Netlogon service. DNS will
>   register itself due to the NS records must reflect the correct FQDN
>   and IP address. I would suggest to check DNS zone properties for the
>   NS records. Make sure they are showing the new IP address. Once that's
>   correct, I recommend changing the reg entries back to default, which I
>   don't believe the ListenAddress and PublishAddress STR or DWORD values
>   are in there by default. You can export that key before deleting them,
>   then go back and run an ipconfig /registerdns and restart the netlogon
>   service. Check to see if the correct IP shows up.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to figure out things like this is to download Procmon from www.systernals.com and run it while you start the DNS service - it should show you where it's pulling the dead IP from.